# Как оставить только дубликаты в массиве?

Tags: php

К примеру есть $arr = [1,**2**,3,**2**,**4**,5,**4**];
Нужен результат $arr = [2,2,4,4];

Comment: не гарантирую, что это самое короткое решение, но работает `array_intersect($arr, array_keys(array_filter(array_count_values($arr), fn($val) => $val > 1)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = [1,2,3,2,4,5,4];
$counts = array_count_values($arr);
print_r(
    array_filter(
        $arr, 
        function ($v) use ($counts) { return $counts[$v] > 1; }
    )
);
```